Why doesn't the Dominion employ cloaking technology?
Given how technologically advanced the Dominion are, they should have access to cloaking technology.
Why don't they employ it?

They have cloaks, they just don't use them for their warships.
We see them employing a cloaked vessel of some description in DS9: The Jem'Hadar.

ERIS Hits a concealed Transporter device and DEMATERIALIZES just like the Jem'Hadar did.
As everyone reacts to Eris's disappearance by going to their stations.
O'BRIEN: (checking panels) I'm picking up a transporter signature, but I can't trace it.
She didn't rematerialize anywhere on the station and there are no ships nearby.
BASHIR: Then where is she?
A beat.  No one has an answer.

A few thoughts...

It's inconceivable that they don't have access to cloaking tech. If they didn't have it before the discovery of the wormhole, they sure as heck had it afterwards (since they can infiltrate the Klingons and Romulans with ease, kidnap scientists and steal cloak-equipped ships to reverse-engineer).

Dominion technology is very different from Alpha Quadrant technology. It's possible that their ships just don't play nicely with a cloak. Note how much trouble the Defiant had with its cloak and then times that by a gazillion.

Dominion sensors seem to utilise an anti-proton sweep as standard which is highly effective at detecting cloaks. It's possible that they discovered this tech a while ago and then rejected it as obsolete. What's the point of having a cloak if it's easily detected?

From a tactical perspective, we don't really see the Jem'Hadar trying to use guile in their ship-to-ship tactics. They confront their enemy face on and dare them to attack, relying on the superior tech given to them by the Founders.



Although the Jem'Hadar do not use guile ship-to-ship, they certainly have and use personal anti-detection capabilities in the field, so I'm not sure I buy your last point.  They do have a sense of personal honor, but they don't seem to have a problem with using whatever advantages are available to win.  After all, Victory is life!

@JohnBollinger - When it comes to ship-to-ship tactics, their only strategy seems to be to run directly at the enemy and fire everything they have at them, regardless of any personal risk. After all, these are basically just disposable people.

I think the last point is the big one. They always seemed to operate on the theory that intimidation of the opponent (and anyone else watching) is part of the point. So they want to beat your butt in a straight-up fight that you know is coming and can perhaps choose to surrender or run from, not hide and strike from the shadows like common terrorists.

@JohnBollinger don't the vorta operate the ships? I think it's mentioned when they secure a ship and find that it has no mains screen

@Andrey - I'm reasonably sure it's a team effort. The Vorta give orders and the Jem'Hadar carry them out at their discretion

The Vorta can command the ships, the Jem'Hadar operate them.

@Andrey - The have sensors and such, just not a big screen. All the Jem'Hadar get to see is a plotting table.

@Andrey I'm just adding to Michael Bonnet's point The Vorta command the ships, the Jem'Hadar operate them, and the Founders aka the changelings command both the Vorta and the Jem'Hadar.

My point was that as the Vorta command the ships, saying that cloak isn't used because it's the Jem'Hadar way sounds like a weak argument. The Vorta seem all about using cloak and dagger to get their way.

@Andrey True, but the Vorta still have to answer to the Founders just like the Jem'Hadar.

@LucasWinslow but that doesn't answer the question at all. Why would the founders not want their ships cloaked. I think the tech being inefficient in the meta of the gamma quadrant makes way more sense

@Andrey I know. I don't know. The comment was just me saying that. Not me trying to say you're wrong. Ok?

Isn’t is made clean in Covenant that dominion transporter technology is vastly superior to the Alpha Quadrant great powers?

@Pioneer - Some of their tech is more advanced. Some is farther behind

The Vorta being beamed out is far more indicative of the multi-lightyears transporter range the Ferengi and Enterprise were experimenting with in TNG Bloodlines than a cloaked ship.  I'd speculate Dominion agents had entered the Alpha Quandrant on some hijacked Alpha quadrant ship.

@lucasbachmann - There are multiple instances where it would be exceptionally useful if they had the ability to transport vast distances. The fact that they don't strongly suggests that they can't.

You could say that about your imagined dominion cloaks too.

@lucasbachmann - A pocket-sized transporter ain't gonna send you light years away. The only likely explanation is a cloaked ship nearby.

Signals a long range transporter and disappears.  Either way there's a ship and the foundation of your answer is ridiculously speculative.  They might have cloaks. They might have TNG Bloodlines style transporters.  But we certainly don't see it.
